# How to resize Chrome Dev Tool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I approached my Google Chrome dev tools, only to find that some sort of setting was changed and I have no way to fix it. For some reason my whole developer tools pane is so small that I cannot see anything on it. I tried the following:

1. Zoom in and out CMD + / CMD -
2. Uninstalled and re-installed Google chrome

Still no success, Any advice?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to zoom in or zoom out the web screen try the following shortcut options that are working on me(Chrome OS):

1. Hover your mouse to developer tools then hold the `CTRL`, scroll up or down the wheel of your mouse.
2. Hold `CTRL` and `SHIFT` then press `+` or `-`, it will change your screen resolution.

Comment: On Mac shrinking works, but enlarging only enlarges the website. Solution: Use `command` + `0`

Answer (score 0):

When the development tools panel has focus just press `CTRL +` or `CTRL -` to increase or decrease the font size.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac: Press `Command` + `0`

some characters to meet the 30 char restriction.

Answer (score -1):

In the top right of the developer tools, there is a settings icon. If you click on it you can change preferences such as font size and color, etc. This should fix it.

Comment: Where exactly are these setting under preferences? (My text has font size 2, so it's difficult to find.)

Comment: I am in 2023 in Chrome 120, and i am fairly certain there is no setting for this